# Webpage url without www not resolving

Tags: url, dns, hosting, html

Trying to work with our domain provider to fix the issue where if you leave off the 'www.' from the url it does not redirect to website

[no www in url - doesnt load](http://engagedigital.com.au)

[www in url - website loads](http://www.engagedigital.com.au/)

Is there something specifically i need to tell our domain provider to do? They have come back saying all settings are correct on their end, and i can see the page without the www loads fine on my mobile device - just not on anyones work pcs in the office.

Any help appreciated.

Regards,
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be something wrong with your .htaccess file so replace the following code in .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Note: If you are using wordpress then it will work fine.

Comment: We are using wordpress, but if i dont see a .htaccess file within the root ftp folder, should i create one myself?